# How to start with clearcanvas in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dicom, clearcanvas

I am brand new to clearcanvas and to DICOM files in general so right now I am just trying to get a simple desktop application working (.NET and C#). I have added the clearcanvas dll's to my project but I'm just not sure how I would go about actually reading in a DICOM file. Ideally I would like to be able to access all of the tags separately after I have read in the file.

I would really appreciate just some initial code that can get me started.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something as simple as this:

```
string filename = "file.dcm";
DicomFile theFile = new DicomFile(filename);
theFile.Load(DicomReadOptions.Default);
foreach (DicomAttribute attribute in theFile.DataSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tag: {0}, Value: {1}", attribute.Tag.Name, attribute.ToString());
}
```

The DicomFile object is the core class for manipulating DICOM files. It has MetaInfo and DataSet properties which are DicomAttributeCollections contain the tags in the file.  Each DicomAttribute within the DicomAttributeCollection has methods and properties to retrieve the attribute values.

Comment: Ok well that seems fairly simple then. I am currently having trouble making .NET recognize DicomFile... I have ClearCanvas.Common, ClearCanvas.Dicom, ClearCanvas.Dicom.DataStore and ClearCanvas.Server.ShredHost as my references and I am "using ClearCanvas". When I build this by itself its all good, but when I add in your code, specifically the DicomFile and DicomReadOptions and build it says "the type or namespace name 'DicomFile' could not be found". What else should I be using?

Comment: Ok nevermind I figured out that just using clearcanvas was not enough and I needed to be using clearcanvas.dicom.

Comment: You should only need to reference ClearCanvas.Comon and ClearCanvas.Dicom.  The other assemblies are not needed.  Also, you should be "using ClearCanvas.Dicom".