# About reading a DICOM Image tags in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, dicom

I am seeking to read in the DICOM Image tags one tag at a time in Visual Basic 2010. Then I would like to read in the header. Does anyone have any ideas. i will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287127/net-dicom-libraries/1330392#comment25467399_1330392) question on .NET DICOM libraries.  Using any one of these libraries would allow you to open and parse the file.  Each library has their own methods for reading tags which can be accessed from VB.NET.

If you want to use ClearCanvas, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712917/3429) answer to show in C# how to load a file and traverse through the attributes, it would be a starting point to convert into vb.net.